# Which is the most efficient way to parse a json object with nested array to upload to database

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am kinda new in php and i was looking for the most efficient way to upload a json object with nested array and upload it to database. My json object is this one:

```
"FINAL_entries": [
    {
      "serverIPAddresss": "116.202.80.27",
      "waitTimings": 85.62899999570101,
      "startedDateTimee": "2020-12-27T15:39:45.340Z",
      "response": {
        "StatusResult": 200,
        "StatusTextResult": "",
        "header": [
          {
            "name": "content-type",
            "value": "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
          },
          {
            "name": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=160.000, stale-if-error=172800"
          },
          {
            "name": "expires",
            "value": "Sun, 27 Dec 2020 15:42:02 GMT"
          },
          {
            "name": "age",
            "value": "21"
          }
        ]
      },
      "request": {
        "methods": "GET",
        "url": "www.sport-fm.gr",
        "header": []
      }
    },
    {
      "serverIPAddresss": "116.202.80.27",
      "waitTimings": 69.66299999350682,
      "startedDateTimee": "2020-12-27T15:39:34.308Z",
      "response": {
        "StatusResult": 200,
        "StatusTextResult": "",
        "header": [
          {
            "name": "content-type",
            "value": "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
          },
          {
            "name": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=160.000, stale-if-error=172800"
          },
          {
            "name": "expires",
            "value": "Sun, 27 Dec 2020 15:39:18 GMT"
          },
          {
            "name": "age",
            "value": "174"
          }
        ]
      },
      "request": {
        "methods": "GET",
        "url": "www.sport-fm.gr",
        "header": []
      }
    },
    {
      "serverIPAddresss": "116.202.80.27",
      "waitTimings": 68.22399999810942,
      "startedDateTimee": "2020-12-27T15:39:30.411Z",
      "response": {
        "StatusResult": 200,
        "StatusTextResult": "",
        "header": [
          {
            "name": "content-type",
            "value": "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
          },
          {
            "name": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=120.000, stale-if-error=172800"
          },
          {
            "name": "expires",
            "value": "Sun, 27 Dec 2020 15:39:47 GMT"
          },
          {
            "name": "age",
            "value": "100"
          }
        ]
      },
      "request": {
        "methods": "GET",
        "url": "www.sport-fm.gr",
        "header": []
      }
    },
    {
      "serverIPAddresss": "116.202.80.27",
      "waitTimings": 95.72899999656156,
      "startedDateTimee": "2020-12-27T15:39:21.846Z",
      "response": {
        "StatusResult": 200,
        "StatusTextResult": "",
        "header": [
          {
            "name": "content-type",
            "value": "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
          },
          {
            "name": "cache-control",
            "value": "public, max-age=160.000, stale-if-error=172800"
          },
          {
            "name": "expires",
            "value": "Sun, 27 Dec 2020 15:41:28 GMT"
          },
          {
            "name": "age",
            "value": "31"
          }
        ]
      },
      "request": {
        "methods": "GET",
        "url": "www.sport-fm.gr",
        "header": []
      }
    },
    {
      "serverIPAddresss": "",
      "waitTimings": 0,
      "startedDateTimee": "2020-12-27T15:39:21.824Z",
      "response": {
        "StatusResult": 0,
        "StatusTextResult": "",
        "header": []
      },
      "request": {
        "methods": "POST",
        "url": "prod-sb-appanalytics-us1.servicebus.windows.net",
        "header": [
          {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=UTF-8"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

My code to parse the object is this one:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    function alertBox($message) { 
        
        echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>"; 
    } 
    
    include 'debug.php';
    
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
        
        $harfile = $_POST["arapis"];
        $array = json_decode($harfile, true);   
        $client_id = $_SESSION['client_id'];
        $IP = $_POST["arap"];
        $array_ip = json_decode($IP,true);
        
        //IP address analyze    
        $IP_address = $array_ip[0];
        $IP_latitude= $array_ip[1];
        $IP_longitude= $array_ip[2];
        $IP_ISP= $array_ip[3];
        
        //date, time and day
        $my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $day = date('l',strtotime($my_date));
        
        //harfiles insert
        $result = "INSERT INTO harfiles(user_id, IP, ISP, latitude,longitude,dates_times,day) VALUES ('$client_id', '$IP_address','$IP_ISP','$IP_latitude','$IP_longitude','$my_date','$day')";     
        mysqli_query($db,$result);
        
        
        //Get har_id 
        $har_id = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT har_id FROM harfiles ORDER BY har_id DESC LIMIT 1");
        $har_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($har_id);
        $har_id = $har_id['har_id'];
        
        
    
    
        
        
        if(isset($array['FINAL_entries'])){
            foreach($array['FINAL_entries'] as $data){
                if(isset($data['serverIPAddresss'])){
                    $entries_serverIP = $data['serverIPAddresss'];  
                }
                
                if(isset($data['waitTimings'])){
                    $waitTimings = $data['waitTimings'];
                }
                
                if(isset($data['startedDateTimee'])){
                    $startedDateTime = $data['startedDateTimee'];
                }
                
                if(isset($data['response']['StatusResult'])){
                    $StatusResult = $data['response']['StatusResult'];
                }
                
                if(isset($data['response']['StatusTextResult'])){
                    $StatusTextResult = $data['response']['StatusTextResult'];
                }
                
                if(isset($data['response']['header'])){
                    
                    foreach($data['response']['header'] as $data => $value){
                        if($value['name'] == "content-type" || $value['name'] == "Content-Type") {
                            $response_value_content_type = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                        if($value['name'] == "cache-control" || $value['name'] == "Cache-Control"){
                            $response_value_cache_control = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                        if($value['name'] == "pragma" || $value['name'] == "Pragma"){
                            $response_value_pragma = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                        if($value['name'] == "expires" || $value['name'] == "Expires"){
                            $response_value_expires = $value['value'];                          
                        }
                        
                        if($value['name'] == "age" || $value['name'] == "Age" ){
                            $response_value_age = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                        if($value['name'] == "last-modified" || $value['name'] == "Last-Modified"){
                            $response_value_last_modified = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
                if(isset($data['request']['methods'])){
                    $request_method = $data['request']['methods'];
                }
                
                if(isset($data['request']['url'])){
                    $request_urls = $data['request']['url'];
                }
                
                
                if(isset($data['request']['header'])){
                    foreach($data['request']['header'] as $data => $value){
                        if($value['name'] == "content-type" || $value['name'] == "Content-Type"){
                            $request_value_content_type = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                        if($value['name'] == "cache-control" || $value['name'] == "Cache-Control"){
                            $request_value_cache_control = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                        if($value['name'] == "pragma" || $value['name'] == "Pragma"){
                            $request_value_pragma = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                        if($value['name'] == "host" || $value['name'] == "Host"){
                            $request_value_host = $value['value'];
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
                if(isset($entries_serverIP) != true){
                    $entries_serverIP = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($waitTimings ) != true){
                    $waitTimings  = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($startedDateTime) != true){
                    $startedDateTime = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($StatusResult) != true){
                    $StatusResult = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($StatusTextResult) != true){
                    $StatusTextResult= "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($request_method) != true){
                    $request_method = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($request_urls) != true){
                    $request_urls = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($request_value_content_type ) != true){
                    $request_value_content_type = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($request_value_cache_control ) != true){
                    $request_value_cache_control = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($request_value_pragma ) != true){
                    $request_value_pragma = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($request_value_host ) != true){
                    $request_value_host = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($response_value_content_type) != true){
                    $response_value_content_type = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($response_value_cache_control ) != true){
                    $response_value_cache_control = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($response_value_pragma ) != true){
                    $response_value_pragma = "null";
                    }
                
                if(isset($response_value_expires ) != true){
                    $response_value_expires = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($response_value_age ) != true){
                    $response_value_age = "null";
                }
                
                if(isset($response_value_last_modified) != true){
                    $response_value_last_modified = "null";
                }
                
                
                //mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO hardata(har_id, entries_serverIPaddress, entries_startedDate, entries_timings, user_id, request_method, request_urls, Rq_Content_Type, Rq_Cache_Control, Rq_Pragma, Rq_Host, response_Status, response_Status_Text, Rs_Content_Type, Rs_Cache_Control, Rs_Pragma, Rs_Expires, Rs_Age, Rs_Last_Modified) VALUES('$har_id', '$entries_serverIP', '$startedDateTime', '$waitTimings', '$client_id', '$request_method', '$request_urls', '$request_value_content_type', '$request_value_cache_control', '$request_value_pragma', '$request_value_host', '$StatusResult', '$StatusTextResult', '$response_value_content_type', '$response_value_cache_control', '$response_value_pragma', '$response_value_expires','$response_value_age', '$response_value_last_modified')");
            }
        }
        
        
        
        alertBox("Insertion done");
        //header("Location:index.php");
    }
    
?>
```

The problem with this code is that when a value is defined remains defined even if there is no value. For example, in my json object the last response header is empty, but the values of response header such as $response_value_content_type keeps tha previous value. Another problem with that code i think that the insertion is too slow, in my opinion. Feel free to comment. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please embrace the "null coalescing operator" to avoid all these `isset()` calls.  In your foreach loops you can skip the isset check and just add `foreach ($variable ?? [] as $key => $val) {` because the fallback empty array will not be iterated.  Regarding scalar values you can use `$variable = $variable ?? 'null';` or from PHP7.4 you can use "null coalescing assignment": `$variable ??= 'null';`

Comment: Do not make an extra query to `SELECT` the last id.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion you should change two things

#### First , value remains defined

For solving this problem you need to add else to the definition of your condition like this:

```php
// old version
if (isset($data['serverIPAddresss'])){
    $entries_serverIP = $data['serverIPAddresss'];  
}
```

```php
// new version
if (isset($data['serverIPAddresss'])){
    $entries_serverIP = $data['serverIPAddresss'];  
} else {
    $entries_serverIP = null;  
}
```

And then remove this condition

```php
if (isset($entries_serverIP) != true){
    $entries_serverIP = "null";
}
```

#### Second , that is slow

You can solve this problem by make one query that insert all of them and then just run it one time, with this work you can save time and that is the right way for adding multiple row in DB, look at this example 
insted of

```
INSERT INTO table(c1,c2,...)
VALUES 
   (v11,v12,...);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table(c1,c2,...)
VALUES 
   (v21,v22,...);
```

and ... 
**Try this query**

```
INSERT INTO table(c1,c2,...)
VALUES 
   (v11,v12,...),
   (v21,v22,...),
    ...
   (vnn,vn2,...);
```

#### For more example

instead of this:

```php
if ($value['name'] == "content-type" || $value['name'] == "Content-Type") {
    $response_value_content_type = $value['value'];
}

// and

if (isset($response_value_content_type) != true){
    $response_value_content_type = "null";
}
```

Just do this

```php
if ($value['name'] == "content-type" || $value['name'] == "Content-Type") {
    $response_value_content_type = $value['value'];
} else {
    $response_value_content_type = "null";
}
```

and instead of this

```php
if(isset($data['request']['header'])){
    foreach($data['request']['header'] as $data => $value){
        if($value['name'] == "content-type" || $value['name'] == "Content-Type"){
            $request_value_content_type = $value['value'];
        }
        
        if($value['name'] == "cache-control" || $value['name'] == "Cache-Control"){
            $request_value_cache_control = $value['value'];
        }
        
        if($value['name'] == "pragma" || $value['name'] == "Pragma"){
            $request_value_pragma = $value['value'];
        }
        
        if($value['name'] == "host" || $value['name'] == "Host"){
            $request_value_host = $value['value'];
        }
    }
}
```

do this

```php
if(isset($data['request']['header'])){
    if (empty($data['request']['header'])) {
        $request_value_content_type = null;
        $request_value_cache_control = null;
        $request_value_pragma = null;
        $request_value_host = null;
    } else {
        foreach($data['request']['header'] as $data => $value){
            if($value['name'] == "content-type" || $value['name'] == "Content-Type"){
                $request_value_content_type = $value['value'];
            }
            
            if($value['name'] == "cache-control" || $value['name'] == "Cache-Control"){
                $request_value_cache_control = $value['value'];
            }
            
            if($value['name'] == "pragma" || $value['name'] == "Pragma"){
                $request_value_pragma = $value['value'];
            }
            
            if($value['name'] == "host" || $value['name'] == "Host"){
                $request_value_host = $value['value'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Your second statement i just run it and it is correct. However, your first statement doesnt solve my problem for the value $response_value_content_type f.e. Still when the if(isset($data['response'['header']])) is empty(like in the end of the json object), $response_value_content_type still gets the previous value.

Comment: I updated my answer, check the `For more example` part in my answer

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Comment: I updated my answer again it should works right now, check it out and tell me if you have a problem

Comment: I just run it. It is correct thanks for your help!